# What is the best way for Google Endpoints methods to communicate?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python

I have two Google Cloud Endpoints methods which I would like to communicate. Method 1 sends off a notification and waits a maximum of 30 seconds for a reply, and Method 2 receives replies and should pass them on to the listener in Method 1. What is the best way to do this? I could use the database, but I feel like storing an object in a database for 30 seconds and then deleting it is not the best way to accomplish this. I am looking for a simple way to send a message from one method to another, just like a simple string saying "Notification  received a reply", nothing more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't see how they could be used here. Thanks.

Comment: Here as in Google App Engine.

Comment: i'm gonna say that you should rethink your approach. Are you really going to sleep 30 seconds in a cloud endpoint? That wouldn't even work, because no notification would ever be send until **after** the delay and the result of your endpoint is returned. If you were thinking of threads - bad idea - a thread can't outlive its parent request. You could save the notification and check in your second method which notification the request belongs to and whether it's still on time. Of course eventual consistency is going to be a problem there.